# Splitting in python by using while loop

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

```
df = df.sample(frac=1)  # randomly reorder the whole dataframe
n_rows = len(df)

train_idx = n_rows 
test_idx = train_idx + n_rows 

train = df.iloc[:train_idx, :]
test = df.iloc[train_idx: test_idx, :]
val = df.iloc[test_idx:, :]
```

how to do this work in a while loop?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What are you trying to loop over in the above?

Comment: If you are trying to split your data, might I suggest `sklearn`'s `train_test_split`.

Comment: how to train multiple dataframes one by one by using above techniques in while loop?